# Android facebook Key hash does not match any stored key hashes Widget

Tags: android, facebook

This problem has occurred to so many, I hesitate to bring up the issue again.  But I have read all the similar posts, and none of the solutions have helped.

My application happens to be a Widget.  I wonder if this has any impact.

Just trying to do a simple share using FacebookDialog. When I run the app over the debugging bridge and try to share, I get a Toast message "Key hash XXXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes" and the onError method of the uiHelper.onActivityResult is invoked.

I added my app to Facebook using the QuickStart for Android and followed the instructions.  I was able to use their suggested technique for generating the hash key:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

When I got the toast error message, I followed the suggestion made on many other posts ([E.G.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543539/com-facebook-facebookauthorizationexception-unknownerror-key-hash-does-not-mat)) and use code ( getPackageManager().getPackageInfo) to obtain the key.

***Both methods produce the same key!***

I followed other suggestions and deleted and regenerated both the key and the Facebook app entry, but to no avail.  Other warnings include being careful with entering the key. Nothing worked.

A couple of observations/questions that might be clues:

1. The generated keys always end with a equal sign.  But the key displayed in Toast error message does not include it.
2. The Facebook Quickstart wizard provides a place for the development key, but the Settings page does not.  In my last iteration creating a new Facebook entry I placed the development key in the Settings section.  Is this correct?
3. Facebook asks for "the fully qualified class name of the activity your app launches by default".  Then says that this can obtained in the Manifest file.   In my manifest, I have the class name, but not fully qualified.  I fully qualified it when entering into Facebook.  I also tried using exactly what I have in the manifest.  Neither made a difference for me, but I am wondering which is correct.
4. Since my application is a Widget one could debate whether it has an activity that "launches by default".  I used the activity that with  in the manifest.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: is the `XXXXXXXX` that you see in the toast same as the key obtained from keytool?

Comment: This issue is resolved. As I mentioned in my original post (observation #2) that there is a place for both the development key and publishing key in the getting started wizard.  But only one place in the settings section of the Facebook app profile.  I THOUGHT that I had tried putting the development key in the settings.  Perhaps not.  I recently looked and saw the publish key there.  When I put the development key in, it worked.